# JavaScript Two key pressed at the same time

Tags: javascript, key, onkeydown, pressed

How to get at the same time two codes when i have pressed two keys on the keyboard?

**In it, I only get one keyCode...**

```
document.onkeydown = function(e)
{  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   text.innerHTML += key; };
```

Comment: you will get two `keydown` events. just save the codes to some outer variable.

Comment: See the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here [JavaScript multiple keys pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

http://jsfiddle.net/vor0nwe/mkHsU/

```
zsvar log = $('#log')[0],
    pressedKeys = [];

$(document.body).keydown(function (evt) {
    var li = pressedKeys[evt.keyCode];
    if (!li) {
        li = log.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
        pressedKeys[evt.keyCode] = li;
    }
    $(li).text('Down: ' + evt.keyCode);
    $(li).removeClass('key-up');
});

$(document.body).keyup(function (evt) {
    var li = pressedKeys[evt.keyCode];
    if (!li) {
       li = log.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    }
    $(li).text('Up: ' + evt.keyCode);
    $(li).addClass('key-up');
});
```