# Lookup table for multiple Key Press

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a look up table ( as i have large number of keys to handle) for handling my keys functionality. So far i have been able to handle single key presses as shown below:

```
(function(){
       document.body.addEventListener('keydown',keysHandler,false); 
       var keyLookUp = {37:leftKey,39:rightKey,40:DownKey...etc}

       function keysHandler(e){
          event = e || window.event;
          var keycode = event.which || event.keyCode;
          keyLookUp[keycode](e);
       }

       function leftKey(e){

        }

       function rightKey(e){

       }

       function DownKey(e){

       }

})();
```

How can i modify the above code to **handle the multiple key press** functionality also?? like pressing **Shift + left key**

Answer (score 0):

> How can i modify the above code to handle the multiple key press [such as] pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

The keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> are **modifier** keys, this means that they're sent as part of the event you call `e` and are stored as `e.shiftKey`, `e.ctrlKey`, `e.altKey` and `e.altGraphKey`, respectively.

So what does this mean for you? If you want to keep your current structure, I see you as having three choices; you can

1. write completely different functions for the modified versions, e.g.

   ```
   keyLookUp['37sc'] = leftKeyShiftCtrl;

   keyLookUp[
       keycode
       + (e.shiftKey ? 's' : '')
       + (e.ctrlKey? 'c' : '')
       + (e.altKey ? 'a' : '')
   ](e);
   ```
2. look at these values in you current handlers

   ```
   // inside fn
   if (e.shiftKey) {/* different code path */}
   ```
3. pass these as parameters into your handlers (which take extra args)

   ```
   function leftKey(e, shift, ctrl, alt) { /* ... */ }

   keyLookUp[keycode](e, e.shiftKey, e.ctrlKey, e.altKey);
   ```

---

For **any** combination of keys, you need to track *keydown* and *keyup*, see [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Comment: Yaa i already looked at that question....its getting more complicated than i thought...thanx for your insight though..