# Multiple arrow keys on keypress

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a game in html and javascript that uses the arrow keys to move. I have already tried

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 37) {
        doleftarrowkeystuff();
    }
    if (e.which == 39) {
        dorightarrowkeystuff();
    }
};
```

but that stops one key when the other is pressed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once

Comment: I meant up and left arrow, but you get the point. Any two keys and I could probably figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exist onkeyup as well, you can check every keypressdown and store it, but when the onkeyup is triggered check if it is the same key in order to remove from store.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of posting an answer and didn't see yours, so this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out. I can just look for the onkeyup event. For example, I can use

```
var right = 0;
var left = 0;
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 37) {
        left = 1;
    }
    if (e.which == 39) {
        right = 1;
    }
};
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 37) {
        left == 0;
    }
    if (e.which == 39) {
        right == 0;
    }
};
```

(please don't tell me if I mix left and right up, I'll figure it out)