# Ignore some keys when pressed alone, but not when multiple keys pressed at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler, keypress

I want to write next condition:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.ctrlKey&&e.keyCode==120) {
        alert('Hello');
    } else {
        alert('Bye');
    }
```

But when we begin pressing `Ctrl` key, we see message **'Bye'**. How to disable `Ctrl` key if it pressed alone ?

Comment: you might want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once).

Answer (score 0):

Just make it an else-if where you check if the ctrl-key is pressed. Bye will now be displayed if any other key is pressed.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode==120) {
    alert('Hello');
  } else if( !e.ctrlKey ) {
    alert('Bye');
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, really... It is so easy. Sorry for that question.