# Execute a code when multiple buttons are pushed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute some code when multiple buttons are pushed, I'm trying this as an example but it's not working :

```
    <script>

    var map = {82: false, 84: false};
    function keydown(e) {
        if (e.keyCode in map) {
            map[e.keyCode] = true;
            if (map[82] && map[84]) {
                alert(" all pressed ");
            }
        }
    }

    function keyup(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode in map) {
            map[e.keyCode] = false;
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);
    </script>
```

I get the alert even when only one button is pushed, ( i got it when both are pushed too )

What am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: [javascript multiple keys pressed at once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12444641/3199927)

Comment: `82` and `84` are `r` and `t` for those wondering

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript multiple keys pressed at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be attaching your `keyup` handler, so once a key has been pressed it was forever marked as `true` in your `map`

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var map = []; 
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event; // to deal with IE
    map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    if(map[82] && map[84]){ 
        alert('all pressed');
    }
}
```

This was also already answered here:

[JavaScript multiple keys pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Please make sure you check to avoid posting a duplicate question.

Comment: Same problem, it's working when I push both but also when I push only one of them

Comment: check it yourself, once you push both, you got the message but after that only one of them can get the alert

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, the program doesn't execute the keyup fonction because of the alert, map[82] and map[84] are always true then.