# How to simulate multiple keypress in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to bring up the browser search from a link click.

I found there are some functions like `window.find()`, but they don't work with all browsers. So the best way to achieve this is, simulate <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>.

I have this following code, but this is not working, I don't know why.

```js
function bringUpSearch() {

  var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
  var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


  keyboardEvent[initMethod](
    "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
    true, // bubbles
    true, // cancelable
    window, // viewArg: should be window
    true, // ctrlKeyArg
    false, // altKeyArg
    false, // shiftKeyArg
    false, // metaKeyArg
    102, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
    0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
  );
  document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="bringUpSearch()">Bring up browser search</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: You can find answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once

Comment: @BenN I want to bring up browser search (ctrl + f) from a link click, what's wrong here  https://jsfiddle.net/biki636/Lf7rd7u0/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in Chrome, since there is no API for that. [See the list of Chrome Extensions Documentation](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions)

In those ancient manuscripts people mention [Find Dialog: window.find()](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/find_dia.htm), that you were able to open the dialog, by passing `true` as the last argument, but it's not supported for ages.

What you can is to make a custom search textfield, grab the user input from it and run [window.find](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find)

Comment: This script does not work in any browser, so it's not Chrome only, I want to know what's the problem with this script

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik I have updated my answer, it seems like back in times there were an option to open a dialog. Not anymore!