# jQuery: How to execute a code after pressing 2 or more keys?

Tags: jquery

Remember how you execute the cheat on GTA? I want to execute my code in jquery when I pressed a certain combination of keys. Is this possible in jQuery? Like for example, I want to display an alert when I press `ctrl + h + e + l + l + o`. Can anyone teach me how to do it?

Comment: on keyup event if the key matches your key selection then run the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript multiple keys pressed at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out this one.

```js
var combo = '72,73,68,69'; //The keycode combination you want and It is 'h','i','d','e'
var imp;
var key = []; //this is where I will store all the keycode
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 72 || e.which == 73 || e.which == 68 || e.which == 69) //this is optional. Filtering the keycode only to what your combination has.
    key.push(e.which);
  imp = key.join(',');
  setTimeout(function() { //delete the stored keycode after 3 seconds
    key.length = 0;
  }, 3000);
  if (imp == combo) { //if keycode combination is equal to your combination then alert
    alert('I did it!');
    key.length = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working:

```
var combo = 'hello';
var keys = [];
function onKeyUp(evt) {
  if (!evt.ctrlKey) return;

  keys.push(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode).toLowerCase());
  if (keys.length > combo.length) keys.shift();

  if (keys.join('') == combo) //you have a match

}
```