# How to handle multiple key press for different objects in a game?

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

I'm trying to recreate a [Pong game by Atari](http://www.ponggame.org/) and am currently stuck at multiple key handlers.

The problem i have with a current solution is that browser does not seem to handle multiple key input and that's why I can't move both paddleys smoothly enough.

The way i handle key input looks like this atm:

```
   document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
   document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 40) {
            DownArrowPressed = true;
            console.log('down pressed')
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
            UpArrowPressed = true;
            console.log('up pressed')
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 68) {
            Dpressed = true;
            console.log('d pressed')
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 67) {   
            Cpressed = true;
            console.log('c pressed')
        }
    }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 40) {
            DownArrowPressed = false;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
            UpArrowPressed = false;
        }
         else if(e.keyCode == 68) {
            Dpressed = false;

        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 67) {
            Cpressed = false;

        }

    }
```

P.S. I've been browsing stackoverflow and found this thread: [javascript multiple keys pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Update: the code using above mentioned thread:

```
> document.addEventListener("Down", onkeydown, false);
document.addEventListener("up", onkeyup, false);

var map = []; // Or you could call it "key"
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event; // to deal with IE
    map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

    // D + up arrow
    if (map[68] && map["38"]) {
        Dpressed = true;
        UpArrowPressed = true;
    }

    // D + down arrow
    else if (map[68] && map["40"]) {

        Dpressed = true;
        DownArrowPressed = true; 


    }
    // C + up arrow
    else if (map[67] && map[38]) {
        Cpressed = true;
        UpArrowPressed = true;
    }
    // C + down arrow
    else if (map[67] && map[40]) {
        Cpressed = true;
        DownArrowPressed = true;
    }

    // Down arrow
    else if(map[40]) {
        DownArrowPressed = true;

    }
    // Up arrow
    else if(map[38]) {
        UpArrowPressed = true;

    }
    // D 
    else if(map[68]) {
        Dpressed = true;

    }
    // C
    else if( map[67]) {
        Cpressed = true;

    }


}
```

With this code, the paddles don't move smoothly and stuck at the bottom of a canvas. I feel there are mistakes in my implementation, but i can't see them -_-

Comment: The linked question shows the way to do it. What do you mean by "seems to work only for one object"?

Comment: Show us the code which is not working..

Comment: Hi Amadan, sorry the one object problem derived from a different thread, and i mixed them up, my bad :(

Comment: Hi Rayon, updated the thread with the code which is not working. thanks for the tip :x

Comment: The `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` should only contain the first two lines, so that `map` at all times contains the current keyboard situation. The rest of the code (`if (map[68]...`) should be in your game tick (normally `setInterval` or `setTimeout`). (Also note that if you want to alert someone, write their name like this: @Amadan; by default, only the question owner and answer owner get notified, and I would not have read your update if I didn't deliberately go back in history to revisit my old comments.)

Comment: @Amadan, Thanks alot! worked like a charm + thanks for @ tip : }