# Simulate Pressing Multiple Keys Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, event-simulation

Can you simulate the keystroke `shift`+ `enter` in javascript? Basically when a user presses `enter` on the keyboard while in a `div` where `contenteditable=true` I want it to be as if they held down `shift` and `enter` at the same time. something like the following:

```
if(e.which == 13) 
    simulate shift and enter key being pressed simultaneously
```

I'm doing this because I want the curser to go to a new line as soon as you press enter and I read this can be achieved by pressing `shift`+`enter`. I have the following code now:

```
        $('element[contenteditable="true"]').keypress(function(event) {

        if (event.which == 13){
            document.execCommand('innerHTML', false, 'p');
            $('element').append('<br>');

            return false;               
        }
    });
```

This code replaces auto generated `p` tags in `IE` with `br` tags but does not go to a new line when the `enter` key is pressed. the cursor only moves to a new line when I press another key after the `enter` key has been pressed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing special happens in a contenteditable when pressing `shift + enter`, unless you create something that listens to that key combination ?

Comment: This question has been answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once