# What is Angular2 way of creating global keyboard shortcuts (a.k.a. hotkeys)?

Tags: angular

What would be proper way of creating global keyboard shortcuts (a.k.a. hotkeys) in Angular2 application?

Let's say good starting point would be to get working: "?" for cheat-sheet and "Alt+s" for submitting form.

Should I map "?" somehow to main component and then develop attribute directive that would be applied to those components which should respond on particular hotkeys, but then - how do I prevent input fields from responding to "?".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use this syntax in your template

```ts
<div (window:keydown)="doSomething($event)">click me<div>
```

to call this method in your component

```ts
doSomething($event) {
  // read keyCode or other properties 
  // from event and execute a command
}
```

To listen on the host component itself

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  host: { '(window:keydown)': 'doSomething($event)' },
})
class AppComponent { 
  doSomething($event) {
    ...
  }
}
```

or by this equivalent syntax

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
})
class AppComponent { 
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  doSomething($event) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems `?` is not supported for 
'(window:keydown.?)`. Probably only the codes listed in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/630d93150a58581a0d474ebf1befb5d09b6813c5/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.dart

Comment: On my keyboard "?" is actually "Shift+/", and (window:keydown) catches them separately.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make from your last comment. Is it a question or a clarification, ...?

Comment: It was my clarification attempt: by typing "?" windows:keydown event fired 2 keys on my test example: 16 (for shift) and 191 (must be for "?"). Thus seems like "?" is supported.

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding. You can add some keys directly to the event name like `(window:keydown.F1)` but I think that doesn't work for `?` like `(window:keydown.?)`.

Comment: Is this typescript compatible? the ```(window: keydown)``` says cannot find name 'keydown'

Comment: Have you tried without space? Where did you actually add `(window: keydown)`?

Comment: Tried without space, I added it in ```AppComponent``` above constructor

Comment: I guess I got it. My answer wasn't too clear. I updated it. I hope this solves your issue. `(window:keydown)` can't be used on it's own in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, but my use case is not applicable to specific DOM elements. I'd like to have global key triggers independent of binding to DOM

Comment: The last two examples are added to a component but they are listening to events on `window`. There is no Angular application without at least one component, therefore this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It seems that with the latest rc.4 you need to use `HostListener` instead of `HostBinding`.

Comment: @Dimanoid thanks for the hint. It always was `HostListener`, I just made a mistake.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how would one identify that this is a global event and not a regular input event? E.g. I have a form or a standalone input and if the user is typing there, I still get the global events.

Comment: If it's a bubbling event, then this is normal behavior. You can either call `stopPropagation()` on the event to prevent bubbling or you can get the original element that dispatched the event from the received event itself (check the HTML DOM event docs for details).

Answer (score 12):

You can use a library I created called [angular2-hotkeys](https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys)

It lets you create hotkeys like this:

```
constructor(private _hotkeysService: HotkeysService) {
  this._hotkeysService.add(new Hotkey('meta+shift+g', (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log('Typed hotkey');
    return false; // Prevent bubbling
}));  }
```

Comment: I tried the library but when I build I get semantics errors e.g.   ... node_modules/angular2-hotkeys/src/directives/hotke
ys.directive.ts(11,110): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ExtendedKeyboardEvent'. ... and more .

Comment: You can fix it by following the guide in this github issue to fix it: https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys/issues/7

Comment: Could you submit an issue with some more information? Thanks! https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-hotkeys/issues

Comment: Works well. But can I also put all my hotkeys in an angular service, or does it have to be within a module @NickRichardson?

Answer (score 0):

A simple and elegant solution will look like as following:-

Create a global service, which will store the bindings of shortcuts with clickable elements.
Note:- Use NgOnDestroy, for removing bindings on component is destroyed.

Now create a directive, which will take keycodes as input like this.

```
<button [angularHotKey]="[17,78]">New Document</button>
<!-- CTRL = 17 & n = 78 -->
```

Now in your root most component, listen keypresses and use them as indices for locating Elements in Global Service for HotKeys. Now on getting the reference do something like this.

> I assume you have formatted recorded keycodes in this format =
>   1-23-32-... , dont forget to sort them in ascending/descending format,
>   both while adding it to keypair array in service and while checking

```
if(this.keypair[combo].length)this.keypair[combo].click();
```

`this.keypair[combo]` contain reference of element on which `angularHotKey directive` was added.

Further Notes:
1.) In `angularHotKey` directive while adding new keypair and element/clickable reference please check if there don't exist pairing with same combo, if yes throw a exception, it will be helpful while debugging, and prevent you from doing silly mistakes, and in Angular 2 component class,in ngOnDestroy method define a logic of removing all shortcuts paired with it's child elements.

Visit http://keycode.info/ for getting keycodes for all types of keys present on your keyboard.

[JavaScript multiple keys pressed at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)  A answer with every little detail about how to deal with combo key presses