# How can you create a event listener that listens to a combo of keypresses (ctrl and left/right arrow)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which navigates between elements using the left and right arrow keys.

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) { 

    if (event.keyCode === 37) { 
        console.log("left")
        currentPosition > 0 ? currentPosition-- : maxFocusablePosition; 
    } 

    if (event.keyCode === 39) { 
        console.log("right")
        currentPosition < maxFocusablePosition ? currentPosition++ : 0; 
    }
```

I tried implementing the following, but it doesnt work:

```
if ( event.ctrlKey && ( event.which === 37 ) ) {
    console.log( "Combo Move" );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript multiple keys pressed at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

Really? I am surprised because `ctrlKey` and `which` work for me!

The keyboard event API [is a disgrace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Browser_compatibility). The W3C has been dragging their feet for a long time regarding the standardization of keyboard events. This is why you may see a lot of conflicting information.

```js
$(function() {
  var input = $('input');
  input.on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 37 && event.ctrlKey) {
      input.val('ctrl-left');
    } else if (event.which === 39 && event.ctrlKey) {
      input.val('ctrl-right');
    } else {
      input.val('');
    }
  });
  input.focus();
});
```

```css
input { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Press Ctrl-left or Ctrl-right in here">
```

Comment: My original answer was pure javascript. I have rewritten it to use jquery and it still works.

Answer (score -1):

Use keyCode as below and use in the function.

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) { 

    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

    if (keyCode === 37) { 
        console.log("left")
        currentPosition > 0 ? currentPosition-- : maxFocusablePosition; 
    } 

    if (keyCode === 39) { 
        console.log("right")
        currentPosition < maxFocusablePosition ? currentPosition++ : 0; 
    } 

    if ( event.ctrlKey && ( keyCode === 37 ) ) {
        console.log( "Combo Move" );
    }
```