# Issues detecting ctrl+shift keys programming a video player with eventListeners and an array

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a website and I have a video player I am trying to program basically I have a regular old basic html5 video player...

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoPlayerSkin" style="background: black;">
    <video id="videoPlayer" controls>
        <source src="http://localhost/C++Source/video/introSlideshow.mp4" />
        <source src="http://localhost/C++Source/video/introSlideshow.ogg" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Then I have the JS file

```
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
var playVideoArray = [16, 17, 80]; //keycodes, ctrl shift and p

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === playVideoArray[0]&&playVideoArray[1] + playVideoArray[2])
    {
        videoPlayer.play();
    }
}, false);
```

But it wont play I went into my errors and could not find anything wrong could someone explain what is wrong with this code and how I can fix this? I am merely trying to play the video when the user presses ctrl+shift+p

Comment: Nice try, however this: `e.keyCode === playVideoArray[0]&&playVideoArray[1] + playVideoArray[2]` is not exactly what you are looking for.. This condition, afaik, is either invalid or senseless. Because keydown listen to **one key at a time**, you need to store the current key in an array (or an object, even better) and check if all the desired keys are pressed, please check this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once (or you can check shiftKey and ctrlKey). Side note: ctrl + shift + p prompts the print window anyway (in chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know if shift and ctrl are down, use [`shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey) and [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey) from the event object

The keyCode is the code that caused the event, in this case, it's `80` for `p` as you mentioned. In the following example, you'll get an error because `videoPlayer` doesn't exist, but it proves that it works

```js
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 80 && e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) {
    videoPlayer.play();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
 Just something so you can click and give focus to this frame    <input />
```

Comment: You're a wizard. I thought I answered it fast, but you managed to one-up me

Comment: Thanks to your post I modified it to what I needed it to be.