# how to prevent shift + tab on focus out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call method on Press-`"TAB"` but not on `"Shift + Tab"`.

```
$(".txtPaymentMessage").keydown(function(e)
            {
                if(e.keyCode == 9)
                {
                    alert("You Press Tab Only");
                }
    });
```

Comment: I don't think there is an "easy" way. See here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Comment: @SEUH - There is an easy way for shift and/or ctrl and/or alt plus one other key: the `event` object tells you directly.

Comment: @SEUH Thanks for (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once) it's helpfull for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this works

```
$(".txtPaymentMessage").keydown(function(e)
        {
            if(e.which  == 9 && !e.shiftKey)
            {
                alert("You Press Tab Only");
            }
});
```