# How to assign two letter keyboard shortcuts for a HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a frequent user of Vimium or VimFX and saved a lot of time, now I am designing a tiny home page for myself which will be displayed in every new Tab.

Now the last step is assigning keyboard shortcuts to each element myself(instead of relying on vimium) to save a keypress.

The example I got from google allowed to implement shortcuts for Ctrl+ some button.

How can I assign vimium style keybindings on my webpage? ideally two continuous keypress, sometimes 3 if needed.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once This link gives you some inspiration

Comment: Thank you Mister super cool handsome gel boy !! Amen