# It there any way how to use numeric accesskey shortcut like 'alt + 2 + 5'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

Is there any way how can I use number as [accesskey](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp) shortcut? For example when I have some code like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/?p=25" accesskey="25">link #25</a>
```

When I hit `alt + 2 + 5` on my keyboard while using Chrome, it will open link  `https://www.example.com/?p=25`. There can be 100 ~ 1000 such shortcuted links on the page.

Is it possible? Some jQuery lib.. whatever..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript multiple keys pressed at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/javascript-multiple-keys-pressed-at-once)

Comment: checked, not a duplicate.

Comment: Not my DV. I just thought it looked like a dupe...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible trough code. I don't think accessKey permits such combination.

Bun in javascript `onkeypress` event you can check if `ALT` key is pressed and you can programmatically store the combination and react if it is the one you desire.

Comment: _I don't think accessKey permits such combination_ Yes you're right, it does not pertmit it. > _onkeypress event_ I didn't realizet it can be such simple, tnks