# shortcut key not working ctrl + shift + numpad1

Tags: javascript

I need to implement a simple functionality on keyboard shortcut but combination with 'shift' key not work :( .

```
 window.onkeydown = (event) => {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case '1':
        // something
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: shift+numpad1 isn't a number, it's an End key...

Comment: shift+1 is also !

Comment: how to make this combination work ? ctrl+shif+numpad1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key code switches to an exclamation point because `SHIFT` is being held. Changing the case in your switch to `'!'` from `'1'` is a possible solution. However you may be using a numpad. I would recommend avoiding the key in this scenario and just getting the `event.code`.

```
window.onkeydown = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey) {
        switch (event.code) {
            case 'Digit1':
                alert()
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are pressing `Shift`, the `event.key` will be the character that was pressed. In your case when you press `Shift + 1` it will be `!`.

One possible solution would be to use `event.code` property. 
For numpad it will give `Digit1`, `Digit2`, etc.

Comment: No, numpad1, not the normal 1 (the numbers key in the right side of the keyboards. Numbers only if NumLock is turned on).

Comment: I also try this, KeyCode for numpad1 is 97, but after I press ctrl+shift + (any numpad number ) the 'shift' press event still fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (event.ctrlKey && event.code === 'Numpad1')
```

this works