# How to prevent a multiple keypresses in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm beginner at JS and I'm working on a project to create a game, which is in my case a Snake-game. Everything is going fine, except that if I quickly press multiple keys at once, the Snake dies, because (i think) it's a collision. That's why I want to disable multiple keypresses somehow, to try if it solves the problem. 
My code:

```
var Snake = function()
{
  //this is the direction table; UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT
  this.directions = [[0, -1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0]];
}

function onKeyDown(event)
{
  if (gameover)
    tryNewGame();
  else 
  {
    if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65)
    {
      if (snake.direction != 1)  
        snake.direction = 3;
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87) 
    {
      if (snake.direction != 2) 
        snake.direction = 0;
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) 
    {
      if (snake.direction != 3) 
        snake.direction = 1;
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83) 
    {
      if (snake.direction != 0)
        snake.direction = 2;
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: It took me a minute to realize that you're asking about multiple *simultaneous* keypresses. That's important.

Comment: You might lock input until `keyup` on the same key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the direction changes twice before the snake's shape is updated, and so the first of those two direction changes is actually ignored.

A way to overcome this, is to buffer the direction changes in a queue (implemented as array).

So in your key event handler you would not do this:

```
if (snake.direction != 1)  
    snake.direction = 3;
```

But instead:

```
if ((snake.queue.length ? snake.queue[0] : snake.direction) != 1) 
    snake.queue.unshift(3);
```

This queue should be initialised in the `Snake` constructor:

```
this.queue = [];
```

Then when you update the snake's position (at a time interval), you would *consume* that queue if there is something in it:

```
if (snake.queue.length)
    snake.direction = snake.queue.pop();
// Now apply this direction:
//   ... this would be code you already have...
```

You could set a maximum to this queue size, as it can get awkward if the user keeps pressing keys faster than the snake updates.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the setTimeout function on your key press functionality like this...

EDIT: 2000ms is just an example time. You can make it 500ms for every 1/2 second or any other number of ms you want

```
setTimeout(
function onKeyDown(event)
{
  if (gameover)
    tryNewGame();
  else 
  {
    if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65)
    {
      if (snake.direction != 1)  
        snake.direction = 3;
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87) 
    {
      if (snake.direction != 2) 
        snake.direction = 0;
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) 
    {
      if (snake.direction != 3) 
        snake.direction = 1;
    } 
    else if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83) 
    {
      if (snake.direction != 0)
        snake.direction = 2;
    }   
  }
},
2000ms
);
```

Comment: Seems like a 2 second lockout would render the game unplayable. Shorter timeouts would become unreliable.

Comment: the 2000ms is arbitrary, you can make it any time limit you want

Comment: There is a similar stack question/answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Comment: It doesn't matter what the time value is--it's going to be problematic. It either locks the game or it's not long enough to prevent key mashing (or both).

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend *debounced* or *throttled* function for such use case. Hands down, it is the best.

Lodash has a decent implementation of both [`_.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) and [`_.throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#throttle). Also make sure you read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) to fully understand the concepts.

Basic idea is after 1st call, you "freeze" the event handler for a short period of time. It's still called and receive events, just not having any effect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here, throttling the event would work well. Here's a simple class that could serve as your throttler:

```
class CooldownTimer {
  constructor(time) {
    this.cooldownTimeout = null
    this.cooldownTime = time
    this.startedAt = null
  }

  isReady = () => {
    return !this.cooldownTimeout
  }

  start = () => {
    if (!this.cooldownTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.cooldownTimeout)
    }

    this.startedAt = Date.now()
    this.cooldownTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.cooldownTimeout = null
    }, this.cooldownTime)
  }
}
```

You would have to define a CooldownTimer somewhere, probably where you bind your events:

```
let keyPressCooldown = new CooldownTimer(200)
```

Then you can use it in your event code:

```
function onKeyPress(event) {
  if (keyPressCooldown.isReady()) {
    console.log('key pressed')
    keyPressCooldown.start() // Do not forget to start the cooldown here
  }
}
```