# How to detect if multiple keys are being pressed at the same time in html using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a keyboard recognition project and creating a simple game in order to demonstrate my understanding of it. When I press the four keys: W, S, A, D, it will print out the direction corresponding to them. (ex. W = Up). A demo down  below:

```js
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;

function uniKeyCode(event) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    // console.log(key)
    if (key == 32 || key == 13) {
        document.getElementById("actionCenter").innerHTML = "fire"
        msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("fire");

        //settings
        msg.rate = 1.2; //speech speed - range: 0 to 10
        //look into console to see all available voices/languages
        msg.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];

        //speaking trigger
        synth.cancel(); //cut previous voice short
        synth.speak(msg);
    }

    if (key == 87 || key == 38) {
        document.getElementById("actionCenter").innerHTML = "jump"
        msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("jump");

        msg.rate = 1.2;
        msg.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];

        synth.cancel();
        synth.speak(msg);
    }

    if (key == 83 || key == 40) {
        document.getElementById("actionCenter").innerHTML = "roll"
        msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("roll");

        msg.rate = 1.2;
        msg.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];

        synth.cancel();
        synth.speak(msg);
    }

    if (key == 65 || key == 37) {
        document.getElementById("actionCenter").innerHTML = "roll left"
        msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("roll left");

        msg.rate = 1.2;
        msg.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];

        synth.cancel();
        synth.speak(msg);
    }

    if (key == 68 || key == 39) {
        document.getElementById("actionCenter").innerHTML = "roll right"
        msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("roll right");

        msg.rate = 1.2;
        msg.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];

        synth.cancel();
        synth.speak(msg);
    }
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Assignment 11a2</title>
</head>

<body onkeydown="uniKeyCode(event)">
    <p class="center">Actions
        <br>
        <span id="actionCenter"></span></p>
    <script src="11a2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Right now I am trying to make an action for when multiple keys are pressed at the same time(ex. W + A = Jump Left). I tried this:

```
if (key == 87 && key == 65) {
   document.getElementById ("actionCenter").innerHTML = "Jump Left"
}
```

but apparently, it did not work. The code runs as if those three lines do not exist. What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No value can be both `87` and `65` at the same time; this is the reason your `if` will never trigger. If you press two keys "simultaneously", it will still fire two separate `keydown` events.

In order to detect `87` and `65` being pressed at the same time, you can do two different approaches:

- Track last time each key was pressed. If e.g. `87` was pressed, and `65` was pressed a short time ago, trigger your code.
- On `keydown`, note that the key is down. On `keyup`, note that the key is up. React when both `87` and `65` are down.

Answer (score 2):

For each key pressed, a new event will fire up and call your listener function.

To check, if at the time, there are multiple keys pressed, you could store the key value in a global array and compare.

So, for every `keydown` event you have to push the key value in a global array and for every `keyup` event remove that key value from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of [Bradens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444641/8723748) answer.

```js
var keys = {}
function handleKeyPress(evt) {
  let { keyCode, type } = evt || Event; // to deal with IE
  let isKeyDown = (type == 'keydown');
  keys[keyCode] = isKeyDown;

  // test: enter & shift key pressed down 
  if(isKeyDown && keys[13] && keys[16]){
    console.log('enter + shift pressed')
  }
};

window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyPress);
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Spankied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428641/17436626)'s answer work well with console log but this will stop working correctly once press a key, change browser tab, release key, and then get back to your application tab.
Your code will still “think” that which is already release, is still pressed.
Or if you change console.log to alert then it will work first time but stop working after alert.
If clear keys `keys = {};`
after alert then it work well (for me)

```
var keys = {};
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  keys[e.key] = true;
  if (keys['1'] && keys['2']) {
    alert('1 + 2');
    keys = {}; // add this will work well
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  keys[e.key] = false;
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is use JQuery's keypress event and pass the value to a switch in order to know the multiple keys pressed:

```
    $(document).keypress(function(evt){
        var x = evt.which || evt.keyCode; 
        console.log(x);
    switch(evt.keyCode){
        case 119:
            //alert("Key press  \"W\"");
            //Go to North coordinates
        break;
        case 115:
            //alert("Key press \"S\"");
            //Go to South soordinates
        break;                
        case 97:
            //alert("Go to \"East\"");
        break;           
        case 100:
            //alert("Se presionó la flecha \"West\"");
            // ... 
        break; 
        case 113:
            ...
        break;
        case 101:
            ...
        break;       
        case 122:
            ...
        break;
        case 99:
            ...
        break;                
        case 13:
            ...
        break;}
```

You can set any key you want with their ascii code

Or if you want only JS try:

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("keypress", myFunction);

function myFunction(evt) {
    var x = evt.which || evt.keyCode; 
    console.log(x);
    //Switch here
    //...
}
```

Maybe you need some flags in order to know wich key has pressed (or not).

Comment: I downvoted because the switch will not detect both keys pressed. The note about flags is just blurring the answer.

Comment: Hi Jan, I'm sad because my answer was not helpful, you can try the solution proposed by Braden in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript