# "Glitches" when using onkeydown with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

When holding a single arrow key down the function works correctly.

However, the problem occurs when I then hold a second arrow key and release the second key the first held key is no longer detected.

A simplified version of my functions are as follows:

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){  
  if ([37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){
    var key_pressed = e.keyCode || e.which;
    console.log(key_pressed + " is UP")
  }

  if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};


document.body.onkeydown = function(e){  
  if ([37,38,39,40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1){
    var key_pressed = e.keyCode || e.which;
    console.log(key_pressed + " is DOWN")
  }

  if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

};
```

So, if I hold the UP arrow key, it says `38 is DOWN` repeatedly whileI am holding the key.
Then if I press the RIGHT arrow key it says `39 is DOWN`repeatedly while I am holding both keys.
Then if I let go of the RIGHT arrow key it says `39 is UP`.

**My expectation would be for it to then continue to say `38 is DOWN` repeatedly again since I am still holding the UP arrow. It does not, however do this.**

Why is this happening? What should I do to fix this so that my arrow key is still detected as being held down?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize an interval timer for each arrow key, which runs when they've been pressed.

Clear each arrow's interval timer when they've been released:

```js
var timer = [];
    
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){  
  let key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ([37,38,39,40].includes(key)) {
    console.log(key + " is UP");
    clearTimeout(timer[key]);      // stop this key's timer
    timer[key] = null;             // clear it so it can be initialized again
  }

  if ([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].includes(e.keyCode)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};

document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  let key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ([37,38,39,40].includes(key) && !timer[key]) {
    clearTimeout(timer[key]);
    timer[key] = setInterval(() => {  // create a timer for this key
      console.log(key + " is DOWN")
    }, 100);
  }

  if ([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].includes(key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arrow key *is* still being detected as held down: its `keydown` event has fired and its `keyup` event hasn't. `keyup` and `keydown` only fire when something *changes*, with one exception: the OS-generated keyboard repeat events. (You can filter those out by checking `e.repeat`.)

If you want an easy way to see what's currently held down, you'll have to maintain that list yourself:

```
const keysHeld = {};

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
  keysHeld[evt.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', evt => {
  keysHeld[evt.keyCode] = false;
});
```

(Note that [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated and you should use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) if possible.)

Comment: Hmm, checked into the use of `code` instead. It seems not all browsers currently support it, and most that do support it have only been supporting it for the last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this behaviour by keeping track of the pressed keys using an array and watch the array using a timer.

```js
var keysDown = new Array();
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    var key_pressed = e.keyCode || e.which;

    for (var a = 0; a < keysDown.length; a++) {
      if (keysDown[a] == key_pressed) {
        keysDown.splice(a, 1);
      }
    }
  }

};

function update() {
  var message = "";
  for (var a = 0; a < keysDown.length; a++) {
    message += keysDown[a] + " is down ";

  }
  if (message != "") {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(update, 20);

document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    var key_pressed = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var found = false;
    for (var a = 0; a < keysDown.length; a++) {
      if (keysDown[a] == key_pressed) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      keysDown.push(key_pressed)
    }
  }
};
```