# Pure JavaScript to detect only Ctrl+Q shortcuts

Tags: javascript

I want to use shortcut to handle a task in Javascript (not JQuery or any Javascript libraries). For example, I want to use Ctrl+Q to write an alert. My issue is only to use Ctrl+Q, combination of other keys such as Ctrl+Q+other key will not handle the alert. How can I do?

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 81) console.log('alert');
});
```

I only want Ctrl+Q work, not for Ctrl+Shift+Q, Ctrl+Alt+Q, Ctrl+Q+(some key else)

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Just ensure none of the other three modifiers are pressed:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 81 && !(event.shiftKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey)) console.log("alert");
});
```

Comment: This isn't checking whether or not the user is also holding down another keyCode, such as Ctrl+E+Q

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that @Seth.

Comment: Yes, I knew this way, but it is not enough. For example Ctrl+Q+A still works. I don't want to check every key. It is so strange !

Answer (score 0):

The code below should solve your problem(*Updated Code*):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
var map = [];
  onkeyup = function(e){
    map.push(e.key);
    console.log(map);
    if(map.length == 2){
      console.log("CTRL + Q was pressed",map.indexOf("q") > -1 && map.indexOf("Control") > -1)
    }

    onkeydown = function(e){
      // console.log(map);
    }
  }


});
```

If any other button is pressed along with **ctrl** (For instance: *ctrl+shift+Q* or *ctrl+alt+q*), it returns **false**!! Let me know if that solves your problem. Cheers!!

Comment: This would give a false positive if i pressed something like Ctrl+E+Q

Comment: This way is same to @Jack Bashford

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to keep track of what keys are pressed with `keydown` and which keys are released with `keyup`, then, when a new key is pressed, you would check for only Ctrl and Q currently being down.

Something like this should work:

```js
var keysPressed = [];

function onPressOrRelease(event) {
  if (event.type === "keydown") {
    if (!keysPressed.includes(event.keyCode))
      keysPressed.push(event.keyCode)
  } else if (event.type === "keyup")
    keysPressed.splice(keysPressed.indexOf(event.keyCode), 1);

  let ctrlQPressed = keysPressed.includes(81) && keysPressed.includes(17) && !keysPressed.some(a => a !== 81 && a !== 17)
  if (ctrlQPressed)
    console.log("pressed");
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", onPressOrRelease);
document.addEventListener("keyup", onPressOrRelease);
```

You'll want to make sure keys don't get added multiple times and may want to clear the array on focus loss (since using control it may lose focus when releasing)

Comment: I'm not sure why someone thought this was worthy of a down vote but I'm pretty sure this is the only way to tell for instance that someone isn't holding down 'Q+E+Ctrl' or any other combo of Ctrl+Q+(some key else) as requested in the question