# How can I choose one of two submit buttons using jQuery keydown when submitting?

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, keydown

My form has two "save"-buttons - one for saving and redirecting to the Index view, and one for saving and returning to the Edit view.

With mouse click operation it works as it should, but I want to be able to press CTRL+S to save and redirect back to the Edit view.

This is the Edit form:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" id="myForm">
    <!-- more form items -->
    <button type="submit" name="save" value="">
        Save and go to index
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="save" value="stay">
        Save and stay here
    </button>
</form>
```

This is the controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, string save, [Bind("form fields")] Model model)
{
    // save form data and stuff

    if (save == "stay") // "save" is the name of the submit buttons
    {
        return View(auto.Map<ViewModel>(model));
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This is the key handling jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 's') {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("[name=save]").val('stay');
            $("#myForm").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am setting the value for the submit-button to "stay", in an attempt to get returned to the Edit-view after save, as per my controller method logic, but I get redirected to the Index-view anyway.

If I mouseclick the "stay"-button, the value "stay" is received by the controller. If I keypress CTRL+S, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values set on a button are only sent on click. They are not included when using `.submit()`. This is expected behaviour.

Simple solution would be to manage this with a handler which will work in lieu of your existing `keydown` binding.

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="save" value="" />
  <button type="submit" data-save="">Save and go to index</button>
  <button type="submit" data-save="stay">Save and stay here</button>
</form>
```

Notice we've removed the name/value attributes and can now utilise the hidden input which will always be sent to the server.

```
$(':submit[data-save]').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // 1
  const saveValue = $(this).data('save') || ''; // 2
  $('[name=save]').val(saveValue); // 3
  $('#myForm').submit(); // 4
});
```

In a nutshell...

1. `event.preventDefault()` prevents the button submitting the form
2. `saveValue` is set to whatever we've declared in the data attributes
3. updates the hidden input with the associated value
4. submits the form

Your `keydown` binding will still work, untouched.

Answer (score 1):

There are two buttons here, so I'm unclear which you're trying to change, or both, but this code sets the value attribute of both buttons to "stay" when ctl + s is pressed. Did this with help from this answer:

[How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

```js
$(window).bind('keydown', onkeydown);
$(window).bind('keyup', onkeyup);

var map = {}; // You could also use an array
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e) {
  e = e || event; // to deal with IE
  map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
  if (map[17] && map[83]) { // CTRL+s
    $("button[name='save']").each((i, e) => {
      $(e).val("stay");
    });
    console.log("success");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click in this window and press ctl + s</h2> 
<form asp-action="Edit" id="myForm">
  <!-- more form items -->
  <button type="submit" name="save" value="">
        Save and go to index
    </button>
  <button type="submit" name="save" value="stay">
        Save and stay here
    </button>
</form>
```