# How to add multiple key strokes on JavaScript Keyboard listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In JavaScript there are Event Listeners for keyboard strokes, but I do not know how to add more than one. Much like in Word when you press Ctrl + I or Cmd + I (on Mac), I was wondering how you do this in JavaScript (if possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered, I found this answer:
[How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)
by searching for "multiple keystrokes javascript" on google.

Go to section **[B]** in that article