# Enter multiple characters at a time in js

Tags: javascript, events

I made the hockey game.But two players can't move at the same time .And one must not move to move the other.In fact, when one moves and the other clicks on the start button The first one stops I'll send you the codes if you like.I used onkeydown in the body

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Your problem as already been asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript