# Smooth keyboard input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have started to program in Javascript to make a 3D application with WebGL. I need to receive the keyboard inputs in an other way, because the way I do it, like this:

```
var keys = {};
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) =>  {
    keys[e.which] = true;

    updateKeys();
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) =>  {
    delete keys[e.which];

    updateKeys();
});



function updateKeys() {
    for(var i in keys) {
        if(keys[87] === true) {
            //Move
        }
    }
}
```

produces a very rough result and there is stuttering. Is there some way I can get a smooth input?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Comment: @MoloF I don't get how this program should work, I started programming in js 3 days ago, also this is deprecated

Comment: @MoloF so I got how that is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stuttering, because you run your movement along with the key events. And your key events take advantage of `event.repeat`, which happens when you keep your key pressed.

You should do two things:

1. In your `keydown` listener, add the following line to ignore repeated presses:

```js
if (e.repeat) return;
```

2. Move your movement logic somewhere else, namely `window.requestAnimationFrame()` handler.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope you'll be comfortable with `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Comment: It's absolutely no problem, because I use `requestAnimationFrame()` anyways.