# keydown event incosistently responds to multiple keys being pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `keydown` and `keyup` events to track which keys are currently being pressed, but the results are somewhat incosistent. If I'm holding left arrow (`37`) and up arrow (`38`) and try to hold space (`32`) it doesn't get detected. However if I'm holding right arrow (`39`) instead of left, I can press space and it works just fine. Is the implementation wrong or could it be a bug in the browser? I've tested on Chrome and Firefox and got the same results.

Here's my code:

```js
let activeKeys = [];

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  activeKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
  updateList();
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  activeKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
  updateList();
});

let updateList = () => {
  let div = document.getElementById('test');
  let html = '';

  for (let keyCode in activeKeys) {
    if (activeKeys[keyCode]) html += `<p>${keyCode}</p>`;
  }

  div.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Comment: Also good to know: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/keyboard-multiple-key-press-problem