# Event listener for multiple keys in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I would like to have an event listener to detect when command+c is pressed so that I can copy something to the clipboard. How do I listen for multiple keys? I have tried something using `useState`, `useEffect`, and `document.addEventListener`, but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
const [metaPressed, setMetaPressed] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      
      if (e.key === 'Meta') setMetaPressed(true)
        
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

      if (e.key === 'Meta') setMetaPressed(false)
      
    })
  })
```

Comment: Not sure but this question can help: [How to detect if multiple keys are pressed at once using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript)

Comment: @HanYolo call what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work?

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {  
        e.preventDefault();
        if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.code === 'KeyC') {
            console.log('fire!')
        }  
    })
})
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can listen for mentioned key events

```
useEffect(() => {
  const callback = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    // event.metaKey - pressed Command key on Macs
    // event.ctrlKey - pressed Control key on Linux or Windows
    if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && event.code === 'KeyC') {
      console.log('Pressed Command/Control + C');
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('keydown', callback);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', callback);
  };
}, []);
```

It's also important to always unsubscribe in React cleanup function.

*Note:* Do not use `event.preventDefault()` because that will block all user events like `Control + C` to copy text and that will be annoying for users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.metaKey and `event.ctrlKey` to watch for special keys in Mac

Comment: Hi, preceding answer contains already what you suggest here