# How can I diagonally move an element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an article with a red background, you can move it using WASD keys, however, the real trouble comes in when I try to create a diagonal movement (for ex, if W and D are pressed, the article should go to the top right corner), it doesn't seem to work:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {

    var oldLeft = getComputedStyle(document.body).left,
        newLeft;

    var oldTop = getComputedStyle(document.body).top,
        newTop;


    oldLeft = parseInt(oldLeft, 10);
    oldTop = parseInt(oldTop, 10);

    console.log(event);

    if ( event.key == 'a') {
        newLeft = oldLeft - 10;
    }
    else if ( event.key == 'd') {
        newLeft = oldLeft + 10;
    }
    else if (event.key == 'w') {
        newTop = oldTop - 10;
    }
    else if (event.key == 's') {
        newTop = oldTop + 10;
    }
  
  //HERE
    if ((event.key =='w') ||  (event.key == 'd')) {
        newLeft = oldLeft + 10;
        newTop = oldTop - 10;
    }
    
    

    document.body.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
    document.body.style.top = newTop + 'px';


});
```

```css
  
  article {
    width: 33.75em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f6be00;
    /*border: 4px solid white;*/
    border-radius: 1.25em;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    
  }

body {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article class="article">
        <ul id="browser">

        </ul>

        <ul id="user">

        </ul>
    </article>
    

    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It goes to the top right corner but that happens even when I don't press W and D at the same time.

Comment: snippet doesnt work for me, but ... instead of OR use AND? `||` to `&&`

Comment: Unfortunately, if I add "&&", it doesn't go to the top right corner when I press W and D at the same time.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keydown` events to collect keys to an array, and `keyup` events to wait until all keys are un-pressed to execute the changes:

```js
var clicked = {};

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  clicked[event.key] = false; // collect keys an init as false
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  clicked[event.key] = true; // change keys to true

  // if not all keys are true don't execute anything
  if (!Object.values(clicked).every(Boolean)) return;

  var left = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).left, 10);

  var top = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).top, 10);

  // get the clicked keys
  const keys = Object.keys(clicked);

  // iterate them and change the values
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'a':
        {
          left -= 10;
          break;
        }

      case 'd':
        {
          left += 10;
          break;
        }

      case 'w':
        {
          top -= 10;
          break;
        }

      case 's':
        {
          top += 10;
          break;
        }
    }
  });

  clicked = {}; // clear clicked keys

  document.body.style.left = left + 'px';
  document.body.style.top = top + 'px';
});
```

```css
article {
  width: 33.75em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f6be00;
  /*border: 4px solid white;*/
  border-radius: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<article class="article"></article>
```