# How do I make the player move in two different directions at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I've been trying to test my keycode skills, and made a new pen with a 'player' moving.
but.. I haven't figured out how to make the player move two different directions (for example moving diagonally). Does anyone know what is missing in my current written code?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

https: //codepen.io/Skysurfer_kon/pen/BaWNQqb?editors=1010

(The link is dismantled, to go on the link, combine the https: to the rest)

Comment: Possible duplicate. Go through this once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Comment: Please consider proving a [MCVE] here , instead of us needing to go offsite to find any code. Don't just mangle the link to get around the requirement to post code with external examples.

Comment: But I don't know how to copy paste my code into stack overflow properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even while pressing multiple keys, each `keydown` and `keyup` trigger an event.

So what you can do is to have a `keys` map object which stores what keys are being pressed at the moment when a new `keydown` event happens.

Have updated your code. It works now.

```
<body>
    <div><img id = "player" src="https://i.ibb.co/3zzPvKT/Annoying-Dog-sprite.png"></div>
</body>

<script>
var frame = 0;
var y = 6;
var x = 453;
var facingleft = true;
var facingright = false;
  var keys = {};
  
  document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  });
  
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  
  if (keys[37]) {
    frame++;
    x -= 5;
    player.style.left= (x) + "px";
    if (frame == 1) {
      player.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/0t55kL0/doggo-00.png';
    }
    if (frame == 2) {
      player.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/Y3q13J6/doggo-01.png';
    }
    if (frame == 3) {
      frame = 1;
      player.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/0t55kL0/doggo-00.png';
    }  
  }
  
  if (keys[39]) {
    x += 5;
    frame++;
    player.style.left = (x) + "px";
    if (frame == 1) {
      player.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/NLHJBnJ/doggo-02.png';
    }
    if (frame == 2) {
      player.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/N135wtG/doggo-03.png';
    }
    if (frame == 3) {
      frame = 1;
      player.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/NLHJBnJ/doggo-02.png';
    }
  }
  if (keys[40]) {
    if (y > 200) {
      player.style.top = (y);
    }
    
    if (y < 200) {
    y += 5;
    player.style.top = (y) + "px";
    }
    
  }
  
});

</script>
```