# Javascript: How to handle Shift + Tab inside switch case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-events, web-frontend

So I have been using a nested `if-else` & `event.which` for handling all the keyboard navigation, but I want to change to `switch-case` & `event.key`.

I am facing trouble in handling shift+tab event.
I've tried:

```
switch(event.key){
  case "Shift":
    console.log("entering shift");
    if(event.key === "Tab"){//do something}
    console.log("exiting shift");
    break;
  case "Tab":
    //handling only tab events
    break;
}
```

But this does not seem to work. The control enters shift block & leaves shift block, without entering `if(event.key === "Tab")` part. Hence, I'm unable to handle `SHIFT` + `TAB`.

Also tried `case "Shift" && "Tab":{}`, but this is hindering with `Tab`-only block.

**Is there a way to handle `SHIFT` + `TAB` inside `switch-case`.**

Comment: `event.key` holds a single key event. You would need a mechanism to store previous keydown events. idk if jquery has something precisely for this, with plain js you could follow: https://www.gavsblog.com/blog/detect-single-and-multiple-keypress-events-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript for example

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428563/5518817

Comment: No, the shift state and the value of key are two separate pieces of information. You would need at minimum a case statement *and* an if statement. however, skipping the switch would simplify the whole thing down to a single conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch(event.key){
  case "Shift":
    console.log("entering shift");
//you enter this case because event.key === "Shift"
//so event.key === "Tab" will always be false
    if(event.key === "Tab"){//do something}
    console.log("exiting shift");
    break;
```

I don't think you really need to use `switch` here as some simple `if`s will do fine:

```
let shift = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.key === 'Shift') {
     shift = true;
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
   if (event.key === 'Shift') {
      shift = false;
   }

   if (event.key === 'Tab' && shift) {
      //do stuff
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: the event object has a flag for whether or not the shift key is pressed, can't that be used instead of keeping your own shift key flag?

Comment: The fact that I should handle keyup event for shift separately, helped me solve the issue :) thanks @CaryHarper