# How to add multiple key press event listener in JS?

Tags: javascript, events, key, listener

I'm creating a simple code editor for brainf language as a website as a practice for my coding skills. In that I kept a button for a function which automatically arrange l the code in lines. (Seperate the code part and the ignoring part in lines).

I want to keep a shortcut for the button as ctrl+I. But till now whatever key listening I did was for a single key. But here I have to listen for 2 keys at a time. In totally confused on how to do that. Please help me with a piece of code if possible to achieve this task **USING PURE JAVASCRIPT.**

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript

Comment: Actually I want that in pure javascript

Comment: The link you referred actually wants to do different tasks for multiple key press. But I want multiple key press then one task should take place. This is what I wanted.