# How to move an HTML element diagonally (only with js if possible)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I want to move an img diagonally with js, right now i can only move up, down, left and right.

This is my code right now to move up, down, left and right

naveJugador (playerShip) the img i want to move

coordenadaX and coordenadaY = X and Y position

velocidadJugador (speed)

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    // MOVE UP
    if (e.key === "w" || e.key === "W" || e.key === "ArrowUp") {
        coordenadaY = naveJugador.offsetTop;
        coordenadaY = Math.max(0, coordenadaY - velocidadJugador);
        naveJugador.style.top = coordenadaY + "px";
        comprobarPantalla();
    }
    // MOVE DOWN
    if (e.key === "s" || e.key === "S" || e.key === "ArrowDown") {
        coordenadaY = naveJugador.offsetTop;
        coordenadaY = Math.min(
            viewportHeight - naveJugador.offsetHeight,
            coordenadaY + velocidadJugador
        );
        naveJugador.style.top = coordenadaY + "px";
        comprobarPantalla();
    }
    // MOVE LEFT
    if (e.key === "a" || e.key === "A" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
        coordenadaX = naveJugador.offsetLeft;
        coordenadaX = Math.max(
            naveJugador.offsetWidth / 2,
            coordenadaX - velocidadJugador
        );
        naveJugador.style.left = coordenadaX + "px";
        comprobarPantalla();
    }
    // MOVE RIGHT
    if (e.key === "d" || e.key === "D" || e.key === "ArrowRight") {
        coordenadaX = naveJugador.offsetLeft;
        coordenadaX = Math.min(
            viewportWidth - naveJugador.offsetWidth / 2,
            coordenadaX + velocidadJugador
        );
        naveJugador.style.left = coordenadaX + "px";
        comprobarPantalla();
    }
});
```

English is not my main language :p, so sorry if something is bad explained

I tried something like this, but i was wrong, it doesn't work

```
if (
        (e.key === "w" || e.key === "W" || e.key === "ArrowUp") &&
        (e.key === "d" || e.key === "D" || e.key === "ArrowRight")
    ) {
        coordenadaY = naveJugador.offsetTop;
        coordenadaY = Math.max(0, coordenadaY - velocidadJugador);
        naveJugador.style.top = coordenadaY + "px";

        coordenadaX = naveJugador.offsetLeft;
        coordenadaX = Math.min(
            viewportWidth - naveJugador.offsetWidth / 2,
            coordenadaX + velocidadJugador
        );
        naveJugador.style.left = coordenadaX + "px";
        comprobarPantalla();
    }
```

Didn't find anything like what i need in other threads

Comment: Look here for clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript Essentially you need to record which keys are pressed. I.E: on keydown add the key to a list, on keyup remove it. Then your code can examine which keys are in the keysPressed list and behave accordingly.

Comment: You're using `e.key` with `&&`; `e.key` can never be two different keys simultaneously. It can be "w" OR "d" , but it can't never be "w" AND "d".

Comment: there are too way too many elements missing in your code to be able to actually demostrate the issue you are having, plz update your code and provide all the relevant code, including your HTML

Comment: ... and [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+keyboard+event+down+and+right+arrow+simultaneously+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Yes @Filburt. Also thanks Moob, that thread gave me an idea, and mykaf, thanks too, didn't know e.key can't be 2 diff keys at the same time.