Is there a way to make an element move in a specific direction when two keys are pressed?
So I have a problem regarding moving a square diagonally when two keys are pressed. I am trying to get an if statement to take two key-presses at the same time and then run. So far nothing has worked from what I tried, and because of that I don't know if the actual x and y translation on the square will work. I can provide more info if needed
JavaScript
//creates the function for the lighting up keys 
function pressed() {
    let squarePosY = 0;
    let squarePosX = 0;
    // looks for the key press
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 87 ) {
        // changes the background to yellow
        document.getElementById("w-key").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        squarePosY -= 5;
        anime({
            targets: '#square',
            translateY: squarePosY
        }) 
    } else if (event.keyCode === 83) {
        document.getElementById("s-key").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        squarePosY += 5;
        anime({
            targets: '#square',
            translateY: squarePosY
        }) 
    } else if (event.keyCode === 65) {
        document.getElementById("a-key").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        squarePosX -= 5;
        anime({
            targets: '#square',
            translateX: squarePosX
        })
    } else if (event.keyCode === 68) {
        document.getElementById("d-key").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        squarePosX += 5;
        anime({
            targets: '#square',
            translateX: squarePosX
        })
    } else if (event.keyCode == 87 && event.keyCode == 65) {
        squarePosX += 5;
        squarePosY += 5;
        anime({
            targets: '#square',
            translateX: squarePosX,
            translateY: squarePosY
        })
        alert("worked")
    }
})
//removes the yellow background on the key.
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 87 ) {
    document.getElementById("w-key").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }})
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 83 ) {
    document.getElementById("s-key").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }})
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 65 ) {
    document.getElementById("a-key").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }})
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 68 ) {
    document.getElementById("d-key").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }})
}

function startAnim() {
    pressed()
}

css
#square {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

.squareStartPos {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    position:absolute;
}

html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="html.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.2/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-aNMyYYxdIxIaot0Y1/PLuEu3eipGCmsEUBrUq+7aVyPGMFH8z0eTP0tkqAvv34fzN6z+201d3T8HPb1svWSKHQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body onload="startAnim()">
    <!--div to hold the keys-->
    <div id="keyboard">
        <div class="top-row"></div>
        <div class="button-key button" id="w-key"></div>
        <div id="bottom-row">
            <div class="button-key button" id="a-key"></div>
            <div class="button-key button" id="s-key"></div>
            <div class="button-key button" id="d-key"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--the square that will be controlled-->
    <div class="square" id="square"></div>
    <div class="squareStartPos"></div>
</body>
</html>

I tried to use '&&' in the if statement to add two keyCode's but it didn't work.

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203407/how-to-detect-if-multiple-keys-are-pressed-at-once-using-javascript?

I'm not exactly sure what it is that you're trying to achieve in the end, but if you start moving "elements" with keypresses, I honestly think you should be looking at Canvas

Here's a cleaner and proper way. It will also help you add speed and accelerations and time control if you want, in the future. Indeed the use of anime.js library adds some complication to the simple logic.
The idea is to use a time interval to check which keys are pressed against a global dictionary object that was updated when the keys were actually pressed or released.


//creates the function for the lighting up keys 
function pressed() {
  let squarePosY = 0;
  let squarePosX = 0;
  var speedX = 0
  var speedY = 0

  const keysPressed = {};

  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    keysPressed[event.keyCode] = true;
  }

  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    delete keysPressed[event.keyCode];
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

  updateLoop()


  function updatePosition() {
    document.getElementById("w-key").classList.toggle("pressed", keysPressed[87] === true);
    document.getElementById("s-key").classList.toggle("pressed", keysPressed[83] === true);
    document.getElementById("a-key").classList.toggle("pressed", keysPressed[65] === true);
    document.getElementById("d-key").classList.toggle("pressed", keysPressed[68] === true);


    if (keysPressed[87]) {
      squarePosY -= 5;
    }
    if (keysPressed[83]) {
      squarePosY += 5
    }
    if (keysPressed[65]) {
      squarePosX -= 5;
    }
    if (keysPressed[68]) {
      squarePosX += 5;
    }

    anime({
      targets: '#square',
      translateY: squarePosY,
      translateX: squarePosX,
    })

  }

  function updateLoop() {
    updatePosition();
    requestAnimationFrame(updateLoop);
  }


}



function startAnim() {
  pressed()
}
#square {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.squareStartPos {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.button-key {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  background: white;
}

.pressed {
  background: yellow;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="html.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.2/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-aNMyYYxdIxIaot0Y1/PLuEu3eipGCmsEUBrUq+7aVyPGMFH8z0eTP0tkqAvv34fzN6z+201d3T8HPb1svWSKHQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startAnim()">
  <!--div to hold the keys-->
  <div id="keyboard">
    <div class="top-row"></div>
    <div class="button-key button" id="w-key">w</div>
    <div id="bottom-row">
      <div class="button-key button" id="a-key">a</div>
      <div class="button-key button" id="s-key">s</div>
      <div class="button-key button" id="d-key">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--the square that will be controlled-->
  <div class="square" id="square"></div>
  <div class="squareStartPos"></div>
</body>

</html>



